# How to send float value to fragment shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, glm-math, glew

I have no idea, how can I pass the float to my fragment shader. I want to change

```
float ambientStrength;
```

as a value taken from mainloop. There should be a case ("O" key) which change this ambientStrength to 1.0 for example.

```
case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                switch (windowEvent.key.code) {
                case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
                    running = false;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::O:
                    
                    break;
                }
```

Fragment shader looks like this:

```
const GLchar* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec3 Color;
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 lightPos;
in int lightOn
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
float ambientStrength = 0.1; //I WANT CHANGE THIS FROM THE PRESSED KEY
vec3 ambientlightColor = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
vec4 ambient = ambientStrength * vec4(ambientlightColor,1.0);
vec3 difflightColor = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
vec3 diffuse = diff * difflightColor;
outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
outColor = (ambient+vec4(diffuse,1.0)) * texture(texture1, TexCoord);

//outColor=texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
)glsl";
```

Comment: You can add a constant buffer.

Comment: Read about [Uniform (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL))

Comment: [tag:glm] (generalized linear models) != [tag:glm-math] (GLM - OpenGL Mathematics)

Comment: Assuming you are using `sf::Shader`, you can use [`shader.setUniform("ambientStrength", ambientStrength)`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Shader.php#abf78e3bea1e9b0bab850b6b0a0de29c7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include "uniform float ambientStrength" in fragment shader and use this in your C++ code keystroke:

```
    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramObject, "ambientStrength");
    if (loc != -1)
    {
      const float value = 0.5;
      glUniform1f(loc, value);
    }
```